# Can we convert timestamp format

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have one formula field. I am able to remove spaces but needs to convert into below format, Is it possible to handle in formula ?

Formula Field : Name & SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(CreatedDate) , " ", "-")

From 
**Change-00013900742019-05-30-05:45:08Z** ( Output from Formula)

To : trying to get output in below format :
**Chg_0001390074201905300309073845**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using SUBSTITUTE function multiple time like below to get output

```
 Name & '_' & LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(CreatedDate), '-', ''),':',''),' ',''),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(CreatedDate), '-', ''),':',''),' ',''))-1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhanik. I am getting output : Change-0001492534_20190507142351Z.. Is it possible to remove Z from last and convert 142351(Time) into Millisecond

Comment: Edited formula to remove last character. Use Apex for getting time in Millisecond. Looks like it is limitation in formula field.